# How to make the latest article always go to the top in noticeboard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a Answered bulletin board
like this

```
id  parent_id   name    depth_fullname

1   0   1depth 1    1depth 1
14  1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-4 *Latest
4   1   2depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1
10  4   3depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-1
11  4   3depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-2
12  4   3depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-3
5   1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-2
6   1   2depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-3
2   0   1depth 2    1depth 2
7   2   2depth 2-1  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-1
8   2   2depth 2-2  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-2
9   2   2depth 2-3  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-3
3   0   1depth 3    1depth 3
13  3   2depth 1-1  1depth 3 > 2depth 1-1
```

And when data is inserted, it is placed under the parent.

Like This

```
id  parent_id   name    depth_fullname

1   0   1depth 1    1depth 1
14  1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-4
4   1   2depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1
10  4   3depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-1
11  4   3depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-2
12  4   3depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-3
5   1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-2
6   1   2depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-3
15  6   3depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-3 > 3depth 1-1 *Latest
2   0   1depth 2    1depth 2
7   2   2depth 2-1  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-1
8   2   2depth 2-2  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-2
9   2   2depth 2-3  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-3
3   0   1depth 3    1depth 3
13  3   2depth 1-1  1depth 3 > 2depth 1-1
```

if leaved a comment, I want to post the latest post with the parent post.
Like this

```
id  parent_id   name    depth_fullname

1   0   1depth 1    1depth 1
6   1   2depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-3
15  6   3depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-3 > 3depth 1-1
14  1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-4
4   1   2depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1
12  4   3depth 1-3  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-3
11  4   3depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-2
10  4   3depth 1-1  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-1 > 3depth 1-1    
5   1   2depth 1-2  1depth 1 > 2depth 1-2
3   0   1depth 3    1depth 3
13  3   2depth 1-1  1depth 3 > 2depth 1-1
2   0   1depth 2    1depth 2
9   2   2depth 2-3  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-3
8   2   2depth 2-2  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-2
7   2   2depth 2-1  1depth 2 > 2depth 2-1
```

And Result

[image]

This is my query

Create Query

```
create table tree_table( 
    id int not null, 
    parent_id int not null, 
    name nvarchar(30) not null 
);
```

Select Query
I used a recursive function

If do it in the following way, the latest articles are not always displayed.

```
WITH tree_query AS ( 
    SELECT 
        id , 
        parent_id , 
        name , 
        convert(varchar(255), id) sort, 
        convert(varchar(255), name) depth_fullname 
    FROM tree_table 
    WHERE 
        parent_id = 0 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            B.id , 
            B.parent_id , 
            B.name , 
            convert(varchar(255), 
            convert(nvarchar,C.sort) + ' > ' + convert(varchar(255), B.id)) sort , 
            convert(varchar(255), 
            convert(nvarchar,C.depth_fullname) + ' > ' + convert(varchar(255), B.name)) depth_fullname 
        FROM tree_table B, 
             tree_query C 
        WHERE 
            B.parent_id = C.id ) 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            parent_id, 
            name, 
            depth_fullname 
        FROM tree_query 
        ORDER BY sort
```

How should I change the query?
Thanks for your answer!!

---

**EDIT**

@Sander

Thank you for your reply. But I have a few questions. In the query you sent, the comments are not sorted, so I leave a question like this.

your query produces this unwanted result

```
sort_number          id          parent_id   name
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------
1                    1           0           1Title
1                    4           1             ㄴRE 1Title 1-1
1                    5           1             ㄴRE 1Title 1-2
1                    6           1             ㄴRE 1Title 1-3
1                    14          1             ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
1                    15          6               ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1
1                    10          4               ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1
1                    11          4               ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2
1                    12          4               ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3
2                    3           0           3Title
2                    13          3             ㄴRE 3Title 1-1
3                    2           0           2Title
3                    7           2             ㄴRE 2Title 1-1
3                    8           2             ㄴRE 2Title 1-2
3                    9           2             ㄴRE 2Title 1-3
```

I want result like this

```
sort_number          id          parent_id   name
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------
1                    1            0           1Title
1                    6            1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-3
1                    15           6                 ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1
1                    14           1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
1                    4            1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-1
1                    12           4                 ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3
1                    11           4                 ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2
1                    10           4                 ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1
1                    5            1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-2
2                    3            0           3Title
2                    13           3              ㄴRE 3Title 1-1
3                    2            0           2Title
3                    9            2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-3
3                    8            2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-2
3                    7            2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-1
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: How do you determine which comment was the latest? In your example the `id=13` is the latest, so the `id` column cannot be used to track the latest comment... Without another form of sequencing (an incremental number, a timestamp, ...) I see no way to determine the _last_ comment? You cannot sort on data that does not exist.

Comment: @Sander
Corrected the data again.
Please check.

Comment: So the `id` column indicates that last comment. Does the picture show your "expected result"? Because that just a `order by id desc` to me...

Comment: @Sander 
I think you have to sort the way differently

Comment: Yeah, back to the drawing board for me.